# Loop for reading multiple files with readOGR and output to different files in R

Tags: r, gis

I have a bunch of .gpx files in a folder and I'm trying to read them all with readOGR and get one file in memory for each .gpx file. Here's what isn't working:

```
myfiles <- list.files(".", pattern = "*.gpx")

for (i in 1:length(myfiles)) {
  temp.gpx <- readOGR(dsn = myfiles[i], layer="tracks")
  temp.gpx
}
```

What this does is read all of the files and then write them to temp.gpx. What I'd like this to do is to read them and write them to, e.g., temp1.gpx, temp2.gpx, etc.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to R and I've no idea how to do it. I tried looking online and found some solutions that were specific to non-spatial files and messed up these files in one way or another.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign()` to generate variable names using other variables:

```
myfiles <- list.files(".",pattern = "*.gpx")

for (i in 1:length(myfiles)) {
  varName <- paste0("temp", i, ".gpx")
  assign(varName, readOGR(dsn = myfiles[i], layer="tracks"))
}
```

This will create a character variable `varName` with each iteration of the loop which will have the value `temp1.gpx`, `temp2.gpx`, etc:

```
## i <- 1
varName <- paste0("temp", i, ".gpx")
## [1] "temp1.gpx"
```

The `assign()` then assigns the result of `readOGR()` to the current `temp*.gpx` variable.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And also thank you for explaining, I'm sure it'll be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `assign` is in most cases a very poor choice. Although Stuart Allen answered your question correctly, your are most likely asking the wrong question.

What you are trying to do is a typical beginners mistake. With this approach you end up with several named objects that are difficult to manipulate because you need to refer to them by their names, making it hard to use the objects in a loop, for example.

Instead you probably should make a list with all your objects:

```
 gpx <- lapply(myfiles, 
                 function(f) { readOGR(dsn=f, layer="tracks") }
              )
```

And take it from there.